Equality of $\int_{S^{n-1}} \int_{S^{n-2}(\theta^\perp)} f(\theta,u) du d\theta = \int_{S^{n-1}} \int_{S^{n-2}(u^\perp)} f(\theta,u) d\theta du$
For a project I do, I need to use the following proposition in my calculation:
Let $f: D \to \mathbb{R}$ be a non negative measurable function, where $D=\{(u,\theta) \in (S^{n-1})^2;u\perp \theta\}$, then
$$\int_{S^{n-1}} \int_{S^{n-2}(\theta^\perp)} f(\theta,u) du d\theta = \int_{S^{n-1}} \int_{S^{n-2}(u^\perp)} f(\theta,u) d\theta du,$$
where $S^{n-2}(\theta^\perp)$ is the unit sphere in $\theta^\perp$.
I thought about using the haar measure on the group $SU(n)\times SU(n-1)$, and show that both sides are invariant under this group. One problem I have is that the embedding of $\theta^\perp$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ is not unique so I need to define the action of the group on D in a good way.
